# Why is the x value in my lua table changing after being created by a for loop?

Tags: lua, love2d

I am trying to make a chess game in love2D, and I am presently trying to generate 8 black pawns in the 7th row, but they all end up in at the last spot of the row.

A picture of (seemingly) 1 pawn in the 7H position on a chess board:

[image: A picture of (seemingly) 1 pawn in the 7H position on a chess board]

I wrote a for loop as shown below:

```
for i = 1, 8, 1 do
    local column = string.char(64+i)
    _G["pawn7"..column] = Pawn:new(0, i, 2)
    print(pawn7A.x)
end
```

Now, I expected the following code to create a global variable of pawn7(A, B, C...etc) with the y value = 2 and an x value = i before repeating the loop. It does function in this way, but it also changes the x value of every pawn generated before the present loop and makes its x = to the current i. This causes all of the stacked pawns as described above. My question is, does setting the variable of x = i normally cause it to change whenever i changes (i didn't think so), and if so how can I avoid this so all my pawns print in the respective spot?

-- Update
Okay, so after rewriting my code to be a minimal reproducible example, I replaced the bit that uses the object library with a function that returns a table with its inputs. I also swapped from using the global table to a local table, and that seemed to fix the issue.

```
pieces = {}

function newPiece(c, x, y)
    self = {}
    self.c = c
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

 return self
end

for i = 1, 8, 1 do
    local column = string.char(64+i)
    pieces["p7"..column] = newPiece(0, i, 2)
end

print(pieces.p7A.x)
```

Comment: Can you share a complete, runnable [mcve]? Thanks.

Comment: Also: I'd avoid using `_G` and use a table/array instead. It could be that the Pawn class is also using globals, which would explain the aliasing.

Comment: `Pawn:new` is implemented with mistakes.  Post its code please.

Comment: You literally print `pan7A` eight times: `print(pawn7A.x)`. Also, I suggest that you use a two-domentional array: `pieces[7].A = newPiece(0, i, 2)` and further, that you do not store piece's coordinates fior the second time within it.